# JSON with AJAX not returning value in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Good day guys,

I have a view that i need to search for customer Account details first and not reloading the page.

The user enters the customer Account number and then press the search button.

I have implemented below but it keeps throwing the error part that account number not exist.

```
// This is the View
@model CreditFacility_Web.Models.CreditFacilityModel.Transaction
@{
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="w3-container" style="padding-left:60px">
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Credit Transaction";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h2>Credit Transaction</h2>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Account_Number, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Account_Number, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Account_Number, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <button value="Search" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Firstname, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Firstname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Firstname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Surname, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Surname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Surname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone_Number, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone_Number, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone_Number, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Account_Type, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Account_Type, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Account_Type, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Old_Balance, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Old_Balance, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Old_Balance, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Amount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Amount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.New_Balance, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.New_Balance, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.New_Balance, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Transaction_Type, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Transaction_Type, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Transaction_Type, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Narration, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Narration, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Narration, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

```
@section Scripts {

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(".btn-primary").click(function () {
var accNo = $('#Account_Number').val();

$.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("AccountDetails", "Transactions")",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { accountNo : accNo },
        async: false,

    error: function () {
        alert('Account Number do not Exist Or Other Errors Occurred');
        },

        success: function (data) {
        if (Object.keys(data).length > 0) {
        $('#Firstname').val(data.Firstname);
        $('#Old_Balance').val(data.Account_Balance);
        }
        }
        });
});
 });

 </script>

 }
```

Below is the Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AccountDetails(string accountNo)
    {
        using (CreditFacilityContext  dataContext = new CreditFacilityContext())
        {
            var accSearchParameter = new SqlParameter("@Account_Number", accountNo);
            var accDetails = dataContext.Database.SqlQuery<SavingsAccount>("spGetAccountDetails", accSearchParameter).Select(s => new SavingsAccount
            {
                Firstname = s.Firstname,
                Account_Balance = s.Account_Balance,
                //rest of properties                    
            }).SingleOrDefault();
            return Json(accDetails, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing you want to do is remove that async: false. It does nothing other than tie up the main thread while the transaction is carried out.

I suggest checking that in the HTML that is generated, your input actually has the id of Account_Number and not an auto generated ID. You can manually set an ID of your choosing as well.

The JS should check the value of accNo before sending anything to the backend.

Comment: The Id is Account_Number as well

Comment: I have removed the async:false but issue persist

Comment: can you just  replace ajax error like this error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
    console.log(jqXHR);
    // Your error handling logic here..
}

Comment: @uthumvc Can you please add the generated HTML?

Comment: <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Account_Number">Account Number</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Account Number field is required." id="Account_Number" name="Account_Number" type="text" value="" />
                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Account_Number" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

Comment: Did you confirm that accNo is being populated with a value and that it is being sent out in your post data?

Comment: No I did not. How do i confirm that?

Comment: Use your browser's dev tools (most browsers just right click on the page and click inspect element) go to the network tab and then click the button. You should see the XHR request show up. You can then expand the request headers and see the data you sent.

Comment: https://localhost:44381/Transactions/Transactions/AccountDetails?accountNo=100000003     This is what I have

Comment: After bringing the error alert, it proceeds to show 404, resources could not be found. Note the XHR brings this value when the async:false is part of the code

Comment: Shouldn't the url be /Transactions/AccountDetails/?

Comment: "https://localhost:44381/Transactions/Transactions/AccountDetails?accountNo=100000003" this is the full url. Move mouse over to see full URL

Comment: Put break point in Controller code and debug whether any data is fetched.

Comment: @Jaggan_j, the code is unfortunately not reaching the controller. The breakpoint does not get activated

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/tracefailedrequestslogging